# The meaning of "lot" in "pragmatic lot"?

Tags: meaning

I'm watching the movie The Counselor and Brad Pitt character say this :
"They are a pragmatic lot". What is the meaning of "lot" in this sentence.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Before questions are answered on the Stack Exchange websites, it is expected that the questioner has done some preliminary research. What dictionaries have you consulted? What did web searches turn up? For additional guidance, please visit the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help). Additionally, our sister site for [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) may be of interest.

Answer (score 1):

"lot" (= "bunch") = "group of people" .

This is often used in a slightly contemptuous way.